# Accessing values using XML keyname

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have XML similar to this contained in a `Document` object (`org.w3c.dom.Document`) in my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <key keyname="info"> </key>
    <key keyname="name"/>
    <key keyname="address"/>
    <key keyname="id">13</key>
</root>
```

I would like to be able to access each `key` node and print out its value, and be able to print out each value with its corresponding `keyname`

I have never worked with XML using `keyname` before, how do I access these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple using DOM parser using `getAttributes().getNamedItem("keyname")` method.

sample code:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class SpringXMLParser {

    public static void parse(String file) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(file));
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        org.w3c.dom.NodeList nodeList = root.getElementsByTagName("key");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.print(((Node) nodeList.item(i))
                     .getAttributes().getNamedItem("keyname"));
            System.out.println("\tvalue: "+((Node) nodeList.item(i)).getTextContent());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        parse("resources/xml5.xml");
    }
}
```

output:

```
keyname="info"      value:  
keyname="name"      value: 
keyname="address"   value: 
keyname="id"        value: 13
```